# Selecting an Item from a Subset in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm quite new to SQL and haven't explored past the basics of creating tables and retrieving data and need to write a query with what I think will be a sub-query and/or some sort of join and am a little lost.

I'm querying an Oracle database with a table that might look something like this:

```
| Name | Price | Status |
+------+-------+--------+
| Cup  | 1.00  | C      |
| Cup  | 2.00  | H      |
| Cup  | 1.50  | F      |
| Pen  | 1.00  | H      |
| Pen  | 2.00  | F      |
| Book | 5.00  | C      |
| Book | 7.00  | F      |
| DVD  | 6.00  | C      |
| DVD  | 5.50  | H      |
| CD   | 3.75  | H      |
| CD   | 4.00  | H      |
| CD   | 4.50  | F      |
| Card | 1.00  | H      |
| Note | 5.00  | F      |
+------+-------+--------+
```

Which might represent the previous (H), current (C), and Future (F) price of an item. I want to check the Db for all instances where an Item has at least one previous value, at least one future value, but not a current value. So in this case the return should be Pen,CD.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to do it using `not exists()` and `count(distinct col)`:

```
select t.Name
from t
where not exists (
  select null
  from t i
  where t.Name=i.Name
    and i.Status='C'
  )
group by t.Name
having count(distinct t.Status)>1
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/ISYYR94648

returns:

```
+------+
| NAME |
+------+
| CD   |
| Pen  |
+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Group by the name and take only those groups having the conditons you describe. I used conditional aggregation (SUM() in this case) to do it

```
select name
from your_table
group by name
having sum(case when status = 'H' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
   and sum(case when status = 'F' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
   and sum(case when status = 'C' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```